# Style prevents Checkboxes from responding to mouse clicks

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, themes

I recently downloaded the ReuxablesLegacy WPF themes and I've run into an odd problem. My program contains a `ListView` with a column of Checkboxes. Without the theme, they functioned properly and responded to mouse interaction. With the theme active, however, the checkboxes don't respond to mouse clicks at all. Click, MouseDown, and PreviewMouseDown events don't fire when the checkboxes are clicked. MouseDown events do fire on the `ListView`, though. I've tried disabling the style on the checkboxes themselves but the problem persists. If I modify the checkboxes via a button click, they behave properly.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ReuxablesLegacy;component/sleek.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>           
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

---

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Album.Tracks}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,
                                                      Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  IsEnabled="{Binding IsDownloadable}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
```

---

These 2 methods still produce the intended behavior:

```
private void ExecuteSelectAll()
{
    foreach (var track in Album.Tracks.Where(t => t.IsDownloadable))
    {
        track.IsSelected = true;
    }
}

private void ExecuteSelectNone()
{
    foreach (var track in Album.Tracks)
    {
        track.IsSelected = false;
    }
}
```

---

Can anybody give me an idea of what this theme may have overridden to cause this behavior?

Comment: They are probably suppressing these events just as Xceed does ... Try using MouseLeftButtonDown instead.

Comment: Can you provide a test project with the same problem and with the this theme?

Comment: I figured out a functional workaround for this issue by handling the ListView's double click event and using casts to isolate the correct track from the event's sender parameter and toggle its IsSelected property. For my purposes, this is actually more fluid than clicking on the checkboxes themselves.